# when page reload drag and drop elenemt stay on the spot

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I want to keep the spot for my elements when using Primefaces Drag and Drop how do I this?

With JQuery? Java Script ?

All that I got is

```
                        <p:column>
                            <div style="vertical-align: text-top;">3.</div>
                        </p:column>
                    <div id="mydiv3">
                        <p:column>
                            <p:graphicImage value="#{imageBean.imageFromDB}" id="imgDB">
                            </p:graphicImage>
                            <p:draggable for="imgDB" />
                        </p:column>
                    </div>

                </h:form>
```

Now how do i do this ?

Comment: when I reload the page it revert to its standard place

Comment: Sorry, I missed the reload page part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible by saving the data locally with javascript or jquery.

```
// you save the position to localStorage in drag event.
localStorage.setItem("XPOS", x);
localStorage.setItem("YPOS", y);
```

At the initialization, you can get previous x and y position

```
var x = localStorage.getItem("XPOS")
var y = localStorage.getItem("YPOS")
if(x != null && y != null){
    // set the element position
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Register listener for ondrag event. In callback, save/update coordinates in localStorage. On page load, check if there are saved coordinates in localStorage. If so, place element on these coordinates, do nothing otherwise. Google for particular steps from this procedure.